# In an AWS application load balancer, is there a way to change the path during routing?

Tags: amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

E.g. I have two backend services, A and B, and I want to forward everything with path

`/A*` to A and `/B*` to B - but I want to strip out the `/A/` and `/B/` before it hits them. So for example `/A/api` reaches A as `/api`. Is this possible?

Edit: I specifically want to forward the traffic, not redirect.

Comment: i am also having same problem. have you able to achieve this? if yes, please let me know./

Comment: I face the same problem. AWS ALB still doesn't support path rewriting in 2022. For now I have to use `/A/api` and `/B/api` in all my apps.

Comment: is there any proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: did you find a solution? Is there a solution to this? For now what I did as a workaround is calling the full path and adding `/v1/api/b_request`. However, the disadvantage is that it calls a specific method only. I've been thinking if combining the ALB with an API Gateway would fix the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS ELB rewrite path and alter the path in between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53157427/aws-elb-rewrite-path-and-alter-the-path-in-between)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible, what worked for me is simply configuring my backends so that locally I can start them without the context, and then when deployed, a context is added.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do redirect rewrite rule, this content is for forcing https redirection but I am assuming you can do a redirect to a diff url as well:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/

Comment: Sorry, I was not specific enough in my question. I want to forward the traffic, not redirect it (so I can just use one cert on the load balancer for HTTPS traffic)

Comment: It’s related just like there is a redirect to action there is a forward action that you can choose. Look at the last section here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/tutorial-load-balancer-routing.html

Answer (score 0):

If your services are separated servers:

1. Create target group for service A (target_A)
2. Create target group for service B (target_B)
3. Add servers to their groups.
4. Create balancer path rule "If Path is /A/* THEN Forward to target_A: 1 (100%)"
5. Create balancer path rule "If Path is /B/* THEN Forward to target_B: 1 (100%)"

Comment: had a question here, Suppose we have a paths like `user/explore` and we want to call the service with just `explore`. Is there a way to change the path?

Comment: It can be done through webserver settings. For example, Apache webserver has "mod_rewrite" module for this purposes.