# AWS Load Balancer Path Base Routing without forwarding path

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, aws-fargate, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a load balancer `https://name-999999999.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com`

Also I have a listener for port `443` and a rule that if ***Path is `/abc` OR `/abc/*`*** to forward to a target group (`my-tg`).

On the target group (`my-tg`), I have a target to an ip (`x.x.x.x`) and port (`8090`) of an ECS Fargate Task.

When I do a request to `https://name-999999999.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/abc` is correctly directed and then received by the container/task but the problem is that the container is receiving the request with the path in it, i.e. `x.x.x.x:8090/abc`.

I will like to not receive the initial `/abc` since the server doesn't handle that, it will handle the routes that go after `/abc`

Any suggestions?

Comment: The AWS Application Load Balancer only does path routing, it does not do path rewriting.  You will have to handle that through some other means, like simply configuring `/abc` as the root path in your ECS task.

Comment: @renanz You might find something useful here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53157427/aws-elb-rewrite-path-and-alter-the-path-in-between

Comment: Thanks for the input guys!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below trick by setting up a custom redirect string?
Using that way, it will redirect only a specific URL components.

[image]